# YOLOv7 labels format

Tags: object-detection, yolov7

I'm very new to using YOLO and this is one of my assesments where i have to train a model using YOLOv7. I have stated my query below and also any guidance would be appreciated

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hassanmojab/xview-dataset
can someone take a look at the above datsset and let me know what format is required for the labels when using YOLOv7 for object detection and how to convert .geojson to that particular file format.

Answer (score 2):

You need one txt file per image.

One line in the txt file per object.

Line format:

class x-center y-center width height

No headers. No commas. Classes start at 0. Coordinates with respect to the width/height of the image (i.e. always between zero and one)

Example:

img01.txt

```
0 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1
1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2
```

This corresponds to an object of class 0 in the center of the image and an object of class 1 in the top left corner.

In addition, a yaml file with the names of the classes and path to data must be provided in the yolov7/data folder.

As for the particular dataset you have, looks like you have polygons, you have to calculate a bounding box for those.

Comment: What should be the labe in case if there is no bounding boxes in specific image ?

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257940/yolo-label-format-when-images-doesnt-have-bounding-box) out

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Boundary Box Annotation tool that is compatible with Yolov7 format. While there are some options available, I recommend using the Bounding Box Annotation tool provided by Saiwa, which can be accessed through their online platform from [here](https://saiwa.ai/app/annotation-service/bounding-box-annotation). This tool is very user-friendly and exports annotations compatible with Yolov7.
If you happen to know of any other online annotation tools that would be helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

the general YOLO format is (object-class) (x-center) (y-center) (width) (height).

You can go through this link where the given dataset is converted into the YOLO format. https://www.kaggle.com/code/ollypowell/xview-dataset-to-yolo-and-coco-format