# I need to automate the task of labeling the image dataset for Yolov7 based on PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, automation, scripting, labeling, yolov7

I need to automate the task of labeling the image dataset for Yolov7 based on PyTorch. Are there any labeling tools or Python scripts available for this task?

Labeling the image dataset manually using different labeling tools(such as labelImg) takes a lot of
time. So I am looking for is there is any script or tools available to automate this task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75536217/yolov7-labels-format

Comment: I need to automate the yolov7 labeling