# YOLO label format, when images doesn't have bounding box

Tags: yolo, yolov5, yolov4, yolov7, yolov8

If an image (abc.jpg) **doesn't have any bounding box**, how should look its corresponding label file (abc.txt)?

The regular  label format is:

```
label x_center/width y_center/height width/image_width, height/image_height.
```

Comment: why have you tagged this question with 4 different versions?

Comment: @Sean, my assumption that the answer is the same for all yolo versions. Or at least for the last ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each yolo version you should check its corresponding dataloader to see how it handles empty images. For Yolov5 I found the following: "if no objects in image, no *.txt file is required". You can find the source for this [in their original documentation](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data#12-create-labels-1). Again, this may not be the case for all the other Yolo versions as there is no unified dataloader used by all of the Yolo versions

Comment: Great! Did you find similar documentation for **Yolov7** or **Yolov8** ?
Also, I was suggested by a colleague to if there is no object, to write bounding box = size of the image, with a separate class (label) for no objects.

Comment: Again, there is no unified dataloader used by all Yolos. So that recommendation make no sense to me at all

Comment: You are right. Now I found, that Yolov2, in such case ask to provide empty .txt file.

Comment: Exactly, each implementation has to be examined individually. There is no one fits all here.